# Laravel JSON maxCDN / Chrome JSON Formatter does not work

Tags: php, json, google-chrome, laravel

Currently i am working with Laravel and the maxcdn API.
This is my very little test code

```
Route::get('cdn', function() {

    $api = new MaxCDN("myurl","mykey","mysecret");
    $data = $api->get('/account.json');
    return response()->json($data);

});
```

The header is set to json as you see

`application/json`

Now if i visit my /cdn url the Chrome JSON Formatter should be of course formate the output. But it does not work, i only get this output

`"{\"code\":200,\"data\":{\"account\":{\"id\":\"12312\",\"name\":\"My Name \",\"alias\":\"myurl\",\"date_created\":\"2015-05-17 07:51:50\",\"date_updated\":\"0000-00-00 ........`

I am working on my homestead machine

`php -v
PHP 5.6.6-1+deb.sury.org~utopic+1 (cli) (built: Feb 20 2015 11:25:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans`

Comment: Hello.  I work at MaxCDN and I have a friend who knows Larvel.  Hang tight I will get him to help you out.

Comment: @jdorfman would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$api->get('/account.json');` call returns a string that contains the json data. You are then passing this string to the `response()->json();` method, and that is the output you are seeing.

You need to run the string through `json_decode()` in order to convert the json string into a PHP object. Once you do that, you can pass that result to the `response()->json();` method, and you will get the result you're looking for.

```
Route::get('cdn', function() {
    $api = new MaxCDN("myurl","mykey","mysecret");
    $stringData = $api->get('/account.json');

    // convert the json string into an actual PHP object
    $data = json_decode($stringData);

    // respond with the object
    return response()->json($data);
});
```